# How to use font size and twocolumn options together for article document class?

Tags: fontsize, two-column, article

For a text file `foo.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt][twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}
ABC
\end{document}
```

Running `pdflatex foo.tex` gives the following error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 4 languages loaded.

! LaTeX Error: File `.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name:
```

But if I remove `twocolumn`, the error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

I should have used `[12pt,twocolumn]` instead of `[12pt][twocolumn]`.

Comment: didnt helped me unfortunately